# How to support a hollow tabletop in the center?

Tags: table, support

I am new here, so I apologize in advance if my description is unclear or details insufficient.

I recently bought an [IKEA LINNMON tabletop](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00251338/) and two [FINNVARD trestles](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/80150095/) to go with it (on each side). But the dimensions didn't match and the tabletop is not wide/deep enough to reach the two silicon rings that would otherwise hold the tabletop in place. (A bigger tabletop is not a solution in my small living space)

I improvised and decided to use just one of the trestles as the main support in the middle of the table. How do I make sure my table is stable and will not topple when weights (many heavy books) are placed unevenly on top?

The tabletop is hollow and the inside is a honeycomb paper structure, so would using alum angles be a good idea?

[image: IKEA LINNMON tabletop]
[image: FINNVARD trestles]

I would be happy to include more details or pictures if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to provide links or photos. It's going to be very difficult to help without a mental picture of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The trestles appear to be solid wood... and the top is supposed to fit. The tabletop is said to come with predrilled legholes. Regarding the silicon rings (that came with the trestle?), Ikea says, "Plastic bumpers for holding the table top in place are included"; I think that you could drill holes in the trestles and just put the bumpers wherever they need to be- or just use a dowel rod to pin the trestle and tabletop together (since the tabletop has predrilled holes).

[image]

I would not drill all the way through the trestle-top because I wouldn't want the dowel pins to fall out through the bottom. I would be tempted to glue it, but then again, it would be easier to take it apart without glue.

Also, I'm not sure what alum angles are, and I don't see any (good) ways for attaching the table with brackets, but if you happen to have a good bracket for this, then I wouldn't object to it.